# Latex tables side by side 2 tabulars

Tags: tables

Im trying to make 2 tables side by side, however each table consist of 2 tabular. I have tried using minipage in order to put them side by side, but they keep overlapping

```
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Global caption}
      \caption{}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\ 
  \hline
Conc a & 0.98 & 0.80 & 0.41 & 0.31 & 0.12 & 0.04 \\ 
  Conc b & 0.24 & 0.12 & 0.10 & 0.09 & 0.39 & 0.68 \\ 
  Conc c & 0.20 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Conc d & 0.34 & 0.46 & 0.43 & 0.47 & 0.64 & 0.82 \\ 
  Conc e & 0.34 & 0.45 & 0.50 & 0.33 & 0.23 & 0.09 \\ 
  Conc x & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.04 \\ 
  Conc y & 0.45 & 0.87 & 0.48 & 0.49 & 0.60 & 0.86 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
    \hspace{1.5cm}%
  \hspace{5.5cm}
  \subfloat[Male]{%
    \hspace{.5cm}%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\ 
  \hline
Conc a & 0.07 & 0.15 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.04 & 0.04 \\ 
  Conc b & 0.54 & 0.72 & 0.75 & 0.86 & 0.74 & 0.75 \\ 
  Conc c & 0.29 & 0.53 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.67 & 0.81 \\ 
  Conc d & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.03 \\ 
  Conc e & 0.47 & 0.78 & 0.90 & 0.80 & 0.82 & 1.00 \\ 
  Conc x & 0.06 & 0.05 & 0.11 & 0.26 & 0.43 & 0.56 \\ 
  Conc y & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.12 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}}%
\end{table}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \begin{table}[H]
      \centering
        \caption{}
       \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\ 
  \hline
Conc a & 0.98 & 0.75 & 0.36 & 0.25 & 0.14 & 0.07 \\ 
  Conc b & 0.40 & 0.25 & 0.24 & 0.22 & 0.56 & 0.76 \\ 
  Conc c & 0.23 & 0.06 & 0.03 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Conc d & 0.37 & 0.46 & 0.42 & 0.46 & 0.62 & 0.81 \\ 
  Conc e & 0.24 & 0.30 & 0.34 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 0.00 \\ 
  Conc x & 0.09 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.10 & 0.10 & 0.14 \\ 
  Conc y & 0.48 & 0.89 & 0.58 & 0.57 & 0.66 & 0.86 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
    \hspace{1.5cm}%
  \hspace{5.5cm}
  \subfloat[Male]{%
    \hspace{.5cm}%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\ 
  \hline
Conc a & 0.07 & 0.16 & 0.16 & 0.09 & 0.05 & 0.07 \\ 
  Conc b & 0.60 & 0.78 & 0.81 & 0.89 & 0.81 & 0.82 \\ 
  Conc c & 0.31 & 0.36 & 0.36 & 0.40 & 0.67 & 0.80 \\ 
  Conc d & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 \\ 
  Conc e & 0.52 & 0.81 & 0.91 & 0.80 & 0.82 & 1.00 \\ 
  Conc x & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.21 & 0.39 & 0.52 & 0.59 \\ 
  Conc y & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.06 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}}%
\end{table}
    \end{minipage}
```

I would like to have the two tables with concentrations a,b,c... in one minipage and the tables with concentrations 1,2,3... on a minipage right next to it. If there is another possible solution that doesn't use minipage im up for that as well

EDIT: Fixed one problem, but got another, now i get the tables but they overlap. How do i avoid that?

Comment: I got it to work with 2 minipages and moving minipage up, but they are still overlapping... Any suggestions?

Comment: Your tables are huge, that's the reason for problems -- larger than the environments they go in. There are tricks to play, using boxes but I couldn't get it to look OK.  Will post when I do.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Newer put floats inside minipages!

Comment: How wide is your document's text block?

Answer (score 1):

This is more comment than answer. In your MWE you have several problems:

- float inside minipages: this should cause errors
- table are too wide to fit in text width in the portrait page orientation (Even if you rotate column heads for 90 and reduce font size to `tiny` one table pair is still wider than half of text width. Consequently tabulars will overlap)

For the second problem you can (i) squeeze to unreadable small tables, (ii) put table one over other or (iii) use landscape orientation. For second case you can obtain:

[image]

The MWE for above image of tables is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}    

\usepackage{subfig}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \centering
\caption{Global caption}
\subfloat[sub table 1]{
       \begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\
  \hline
Conc a & 0.98 & 0.75 & 0.36 & 0.25 & 0.14 & 0.07 \\
  Conc b & 0.40 & 0.25 & 0.24 & 0.22 & 0.56 & 0.76 \\
  Conc c & 0.23 & 0.06 & 0.03 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  Conc d & 0.37 & 0.46 & 0.42 & 0.46 & 0.62 & 0.81 \\
  Conc e & 0.24 & 0.30 & 0.34 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 0.00 \\
  Conc x & 0.09 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.10 & 0.10 & 0.14 \\
  Conc y & 0.48 & 0.89 & 0.58 & 0.57 & 0.66 & 0.86 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\
  \hline
Conc a & 0.07 & 0.16 & 0.16 & 0.09 & 0.05 & 0.07 \\
  Conc b & 0.60 & 0.78 & 0.81 & 0.89 & 0.81 & 0.82 \\
  Conc c & 0.31 & 0.36 & 0.36 & 0.40 & 0.67 & 0.80 \\
  Conc d & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 \\
  Conc e & 0.52 & 0.81 & 0.91 & 0.80 & 0.82 & 1.00 \\
  Conc x & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.21 & 0.39 & 0.52 & 0.59 \\
  Conc y & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.06 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
            }

    \subfloat[sub table 2]{
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\
  \hline
Conc a & 0.98 & 0.80 & 0.41 & 0.31 & 0.12 & 0.04 \\
  Conc b & 0.24 & 0.12 & 0.10 & 0.09 & 0.39 & 0.68 \\
  Conc c & 0.20 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  Conc d & 0.34 & 0.46 & 0.43 & 0.47 & 0.64 & 0.82 \\
  Conc e & 0.34 & 0.45 & 0.50 & 0.33 & 0.23 & 0.09 \\
  Conc x & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.04 \\
  Conc y & 0.45 & 0.87 & 0.48 & 0.49 & 0.60 & 0.86 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
  \hline
 & 0,5\_sec & 1\_sec & 1,5\_sec & 2\_sec & 2,5\_sec & 3\_sec \\
  \hline
Conc a & 0.07 & 0.15 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.04 & 0.04 \\
  Conc b & 0.54 & 0.72 & 0.75 & 0.86 & 0.74 & 0.75 \\
  Conc c & 0.29 & 0.53 & 0.54 & 0.54 & 0.67 & 0.81 \\
  Conc d & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.03 \\
  Conc e & 0.47 & 0.78 & 0.90 & 0.80 & 0.82 & 1.00 \\
  Conc x & 0.06 & 0.05 & 0.11 & 0.26 & 0.43 & 0.56 \\
  Conc y & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.12 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}%
    }% 
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

If you use `\tiny` font size and rotate column heads, you obtain

[image]

Based on both options you can decide what to do.